# Всё меняется, Ваше Высочество / Ваше высочество / ваше высочество. Только вы не меняетесь, нет

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Всё меняется, Ваше Высочество / Ваше высочество / ваше высочество. Только вы не меняетесь, нет.

> Как же, Ваше Честь / Ваша честь / ваша честь, мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Всё меняется, Ваше Высочество. Только Вы не меняетесь, нет*.

После *только* тоже лучше с заглавной.

*Как же, Ваша честь, мне это сделать?*

А вот *честь* уже с маленькой.

**[«Грамота.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/51-rubric-88)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему "честь" пишется со строчной буквы? Это можно как-то объяснить? Ведь все можно объяснить, Ваша честь, не правда ли? Кстати, это обращение только к судье?